# ASP.NET Simple CMS

Tags: asp.net, cms

I have an existing ASP.NET web site. The site has a "news" section and I'd like to add some very simple content management functionality to that an administrator can edit the news.

I had thought of using DotNetNuke.

- Is this a sensible option?
- Any pointers for adding this simple functionality?
- Should I look at another solution?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe this is off topic.

Comment: Off what topic?

Comment: I think it is a valid question, why is it off topic?

Comment: @daviy , i gave answer to what we did in our company recently , see if that info is useful

Comment: @David Ward: I don't see a specific programming question. However, thats why this is a community site, and as such, it won't get closed unless others agree. Please don't take offense, it's only 2 peoples opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently we had the same requirement and we did this way

1) Created XML files on a separate box like a separate server it self.

2) Wrote api in net to read xml files and html files and display on asp.net

3) The business access the xml files directly and modify the contents

4) Then can always modify the content and get a preview in QA or staging.

5) We thought of going for third party CMS , but we have to change the complete website.

6) The approach we are using is working pretty fine.

Let me know if you need any more info , with this approach you can save money and you and your business will have full control

Comment: Thanks for this - led me to find this which I think I will make use of http://blog.evonet.com.au/post/Creating-a-Content-Management-System-for-your-ASPNET-Web-Site.aspx

Comment: @david , yeah try this approach , if we want to go for third party , we have build our entire site that way , which may not be feasble when our website is already built , but you can definetly try what we are doing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of .Net CMSs to choose from

- DotNetNuke
- Umbraco
- orchard Project

To name but a few. If you are going to be building websites regularly pick one and learn it well. A CMS will save you a lot of time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

a complete cms (which you have to maintain and manage) seems a little overkill i think.

when you see the news messages as a simple list, you can make a simple CRUD screen for it in which you can set the visibility, showdate, enddate etc. just like any other list of items (clients, accounts, orders).

for editing the (html)content you can use the ckeditor control; with that the admin user can type any html he/she wants.

storage can be done in the database if you already use one, or in a simple database (sql server CE) or in xml if you want.